# Team Foundation Server 2010 Framework

Tags: tfs, tfs-2010

Can I work with framework 1.1 while using Team Foundation Server 2010?

Answer (score 0):

There's nothing linking the use of TFS to a specific version of the framework, with the exception of the development environment that you're using.

If you are using Visual Studio 2010, you *should* be able to target framework 1.1 for your development (though on a Windows 7 machine, it may require an additional download and installation.).

If you are using Visual Studio 2005 or 2008, you'll need the appropriate forward compatability update:

VS 2005:  http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/en/details.aspx?FamilyID=22215e4c-af6f-4e2f-96df-20e94d762689&displaylang=en

VS 2008: http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/en/details.aspx?FamilyID=cf13ea45-d17b-4edc-8e6c-6c5b208ec54d

If you are talking about developing applications that can integrate with TFS 2010, you probably aren't going to be successful with using framework version 1.1.

Comment: I wwant to convert one project to 2010 it was codded in vs2003

Comment: @user - If you are going to convert the project, again the target framework has nothing to do with TF, it doesn't care.  You do understand that if you were to target the code to .NET Framework 4 it would as is right?